# YouTube Video appearing in wrong spot when playing 2nd time on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video, youtube

I'm having a strange issue over at a new site I just created (http://segarsmedia.com/motor-city-rising/). Problem is when you first visit it, you're greeted with a large play button and a poster image from the video I'm presenting coming from YouTube. Click it and a div goes over that spot, along with an close button. So far, so good.

However, if you click the close button and then try to play the video again, the video appears and starts to play, but it now appears underneath the poster image and play button and it's about 1/5 the original size. It seems to now be playing outside of its' intended container although when in inspector, the code doesn't seem to show that. It also doesn't seem to add any additional inline styles as well.

Obviously, I want the video to appear where it first appears when you click on the play button. So why is this occurring instead?

I have a Pen up at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdMqya and here's the code.

HTML

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <div id="video-mask"></div>
    <a class="vidjmp" id="show" href="#"><div class="play"><img src="http://segarsmedia.com/wp-content/themes/auth-story/img/play.png" alt="play" title="play"></div>
    <img width="1920" height="1080" src="http://segarsmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/hero-motor-city-rising.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="Motor City Rising" srcset="http://segarsmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/hero-motor-city-rising.jpg 1920w, http://segarsmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/hero-motor-city-rising-300x169.jpg 300w, http://segarsmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/hero-motor-city-rising-768x432.jpg 768w, http://segarsmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/hero-motor-city-rising-1024x576.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px" /></a>
    <div id="video-content" class="video-content">
        <a id="video-close" href="#"><div id="close" class="close">X</div></a>
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe id="video-iframe" width="" height="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/75pCxGDkuNQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

CSS

```
.entry-content:before,
.entry-content:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.entry-content:after, {
    clear: both;
}
.entry-content {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.play {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -62.5px;
    margin-top: -62.5px;
    z-index: 205;
 }
#video-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 1000;
}
.video-container {
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom:56.25%;
   padding-top: 0;
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#close {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 24px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  z-index: 2000;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  z-index: 2000;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 677px) {
    .play {
        width: 62.5px;
        height: 62.5px;
        margin-left: -31.25px;
        margin-top: -31.25px;
    }
    #close {
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        width: 30px;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
}
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var iframeSrc = jQuery('#video-iframe').attr("src");    
    jQuery('a.vidjmp').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#video-iframe').attr("src", iframeSrc + '?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=0');
    jQuery('#video-mask').fadeTo(500,0.9, function(){
    jQuery('#video-content').fadeIn(500, function(){
    jQuery('#video-iframe').show();
  });
});

});

  // Close Modal/Mask    
  jQuery('#video-close, #video-mask').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery('#video-iframe').attr("src", iframeSrc);

    jQuery('#video-mask, #video-content').fadeOut(0, function(){
        var vidCopy = jQuery('#video-iframe').clone();
        jQuery('#video-iframe').detach();
        jQuery(vidCopy).appendTo('#video-content');
    });

  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was a simple case of CSS:

```
#video-iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```